# set a value into a model, and fail to display the value in JSP via EL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have problem when i read a tutorial about spring mvc.The project have jsp page like:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World - ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>
hello!
    ${inf}
</body>
</html>
```

And when i set a value for the inf in the controller,but,the "${inf}" fails to retirve the value.

what should i do now?

thx

add:
the controller's code:

```
package net.viralpatel.spring3.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        ModelAndView modelandview=new ModelAndView("hello");
        modelandview.addObject("inf", message);
        //return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
        return modelandview;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your controller code. Also, have you got the jar for `javax.servlet:jstl` on your classpath (or in your container's lib)? Test if JSTL is working with `${pageContext.request.requestURI}`.

Comment: i have aready add the controller's code,pls read it.thx

Comment: ${pageContext.request.requestURI} shows /Spring3MVC/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

Comment: @nickdos waiting for ur idea.

Comment: @kaiwiiho Is your `message` printed in your's app log with the `System.out.println(message);`?

Comment: I think you've imported the wrong version of ModelAndView - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your import for ModelAndView to:

`org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView`